# Encoder-Decoder for Trajectory Prediction

Tags: keras, lstm, encoder, decoder, encoder-decoder

I need to use encoder-decoder structure to predict 2D trajectories. As almost all available tutorials are related to NLP -with sparse vectors-, I couldn't be sure about how to adapt the solutions to a continuous data.

In addition to my ignorance in seqence-to-sequence models, `embedding` process for words confused me more. I have a dataset that consists of 3,000,000 samples each having `x-y` coordinates (-1, 1) with `125` observations, which means the shape of each sample is `(125, 2)`. I thought I could think of this as 125 words with 2 dimensional already embedded words, but the encoder and the decoder in this [Keras Tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) expect 3D arrays as `(num_pairs, max_english_sentence_length, num_english_characters)`.

I doubt I need to train each sample `(125, 2)` separately with this model, as the way Google's search bar does with only one word written.

As far as I understood, an encoder is `many-to-one` type model and a decoder is `one-to-many` type model. I need to get a memory state `c` and a hiddenstate `h` as vectors(?). Then I should use those vectors as input to decoder and extract predictions in the shape of (x,y) as many as I determine as encoder output.

I'd be so thankful if someone could give an example of an encoder-decoder LSTM architecture over the shape of my dataset, especially in terms of dimensions required for encoder-decoder inputs and outputs, particulary on Keras model if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to forecast 50 time steps with the 125 previous ones (as an example). I give you the most basic Encoder-Decoder Structure for time Series but it can be improved (with [Luong Attention](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04025) for instance).

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers,models

input_timesteps=125
input_features=2
output_timesteps=50
output_features=2
units=100

#Input
encoder_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(input_timesteps,input_features))

#Encoder
encoder = layers.LSTM(units, return_state=True, return_sequences=False)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs) # because return_sequences=False => encoder_outputs=state_h

#Decoder
decoder = layers.RepeatVector(output_timesteps)(state_h)
decoder_lstm = layers.LSTM(units, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)
decoder = decoder_lstm(decoder, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])


#Output
out = layers.TimeDistributed(Dense(output_features))(decoder)

model = models.Model(encoder_inputs, out)
```

So the core idea here is :

1. Encode the time series into two states : `state_h` and `state_c`. Check [this](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) to understand the work of LSTM cells.
2. Repeat `state_h` the number of time steps you want to forecast
3. Decode using an LSTM with initial states calculated by the encoder
4. Use a Dense layer to shape the number of needed features for each time steps

I advise you to test our achtecture and visualize them with `model.summary()` and `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(mode,show_shapes=True)`. It gives you good representations like, for the summary :

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)            [(None, 125, 2)]     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_8 (LSTM)                   [(None, 100), (None, 41200       input_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_4 (RepeatVector)  (None, 50, 100)      0           lstm_8[0][1]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_9 (LSTM)                   (None, 50, 100)      80400       repeat_vector_4[0][0]            
                                                                 lstm_8[0][1]                     
                                                                 lstm_8[0][2]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_4 (TimeDistrib (None, 50, 2)        202         lstm_9[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 121,802
Trainable params: 121,802
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

and the model plotted :

[image]